# How to use logical OR operator with SQL update queries in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I write something like this query?

I want to update the table but I am not sure how many columns need to be updated and how many condition I can apply. I totally depend on the SQL parameters.

Here is my sample SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRecords
(
@Category AS VARCHAR(20)='',
@Manufature AS VARCHAR(20)='',
@Model AS VARCHAR(20)='',

@CategoryNew AS VARCHAR(20),
@ManufatureNew AS VARCHAR(20),
@ModelNew AS VARCHAR(20),

@CategoryOld AS VARCHAR(20),
@ManufatureOld AS VARCHAR(20),
@ModelOld AS VARCHAR(20)

)
AS

UPDATE table19999
SET (@category='' OR category=@CategoryNew),
(@Manufature='' OR Manufature=@ManufatureNew),
(@Model='' OR Model=@ModelNew)
WHERE (@category='' OR category=@CategoryOld ) AND
(@Manufature='' OR Manufature=@ManufatureOld ) AND
(@Model='' OR Model=@ModelOld )
```

Any help?

Comment: the code is wrong, please say what you need to do. update the category field when?

Comment: I'm guessing if @category='' don't change category else if category=@categoryold set category=@categorynew

Comment: The unit of work in SQL is the row, not the column.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table199999

set 
   category=case when @category='' then category else @CategoryNew end,
   manufacture=case when @manufature='' then manufacture else @manufactureNew end
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition in..

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET (MANUFACTURE = @MANUFACTURE, CATEGORY = @CATEGORY)
WHERE MANUFACTURE IN (@OPTION1, @OPTION2) 
OR CATEGORY IN (@CATEGORY1, @CATEGORY2)
```